# Xcode11 does not allow connecting a label to an IBOutlet on a different view controller

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uilabel, xcode11, iboutlet

I have two view controllers A and B with labels and buttons on A.
xcode11 allows me to click drag from a UIButton on A over to B,
however it will not allow me to do the same for a UILabel.
Is the a way to allow this to happen?

---

Answer (score 1):

You've misunderstood what you did. You can't make any sort of outlet or action connection between two view controllers. What you made is a *segue* - an action segue. You tap the button and we will push or present the second view controller. Well, fine, if that's what you wanted; but a label is not tappable, so there is no action segue possible from it. A tappable label would be a button.

Comment: Thanks for replying . It does allow me to drag a text field over and when I do a function is created in the second view controller that is not a segue.

Comment: A text field is a control. That's another action segue. You cannot make an action connection between view controllers.